# Identification of Unknown Insects found in landfill (tiny, full of hair on body)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

Could someone help me to identify the following insect with full hair on body? They are very small, so I use macro lens to capture them. I have tried to capture them as clearly as possible.

[image]

They were collected from a closed section of Tseung Kwan O Landfill and Clear Water Bay Country Park of Hong Kong. This area is revegetated so the ecology is much like a country park just nearby the landfill.

Comment: Were they found in landfill debris or in a natural setting? They are very similar to the larvae of beetles in the Dermestidae family (carpet beetles),  which are known to feed on decaying organic matter. Adults are easier to identify. If you can keep them alive in a warm, moist environment and feed them until they form adults, then you can post photos of the adults.

Comment: They were found in natural setting, the site that is similar to forest with tree planted. While there are decaying matters deep down in the soil as the site was used as landfill previously, because the gas analysis shows that there is no gas leaking from decayed matter (methane, CO, H2S etc.) I am not sure if the environment flavour the growth of Dermestidae.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to identify these insects? For example, do you need to understand their ecosystem function with respect to landfill processes? Are they very abundant in the collection location?

Comment: I agree with @prefectionist , they look like carpet beetle larve